# Are there any implications of calling the same function recursively within a switchMap operator in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, recursion, angular-2+, rxjs

In the code below, `startFlow$` function that takes an input request object and subscribes to open a dialog/popup that performs a certain operation.

Once the popup is closed, the `openPopUp$` function will return a response.

If the response is unsuccessful, a retry dialog is displayed, asking the user if they would like to retry the flow.

If the user confirms, the `startFlow$` function is called again in a recursive manner.

```ts
startFlow$(request) {
  return this.openPopUp$(request).pipe(

    filter((response) => this.isFailedResponse(response)),  // if response is NOT success,
    switchMap((response) => this.showRetryDialog$(response)), // show retry dialog

    filter((confirm) => confirm),                             // if confirm to retry
    switchMap(() => this.startFlow$(request)),                // call startFlow$ again
  );
}
```

What are the implications of calling the `startFlow$` recursively within the observable chain in RxJS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Can you please confirm: are you the author or maintainer of the code?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ yes, I am

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ If you don't mind me asking, what is the reason behind your question?

Comment: Maybe you've already read it but if not, see the [help center page _What topics can I ask about here?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  [“_For licensing, moral, and procedural reasons, we cannot review code written by other programmers. We expect you, as the author, to understand why the code is written the way that it is._”](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)